# How to make responsive sidebar

Tags: html, css

Hello guys i have page and im trying to make responsive sidebar.. but without succeed :/

So here is my css file

```
body {
    font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
    background: url("https://i.imgur.com/CTT4cRp.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

#particles-js {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: -1;
    left: 0px;
    background-image: url('');
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.content-box {
    border-radius: 25px;
    border: 2px solid;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
    max-width: 70rem;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 20rem;
    background: white;
    padding-bottom: 50rem;
}

.news-box {
    background-color: lightgrey;
    width: 70%;
    float: left;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 30px;
}

.news-title {padding-bottom: 5px;}

.sidebar {
    position: relative;
    width: 24%;
    float: right;
    bottom: 520px;
    margin: 30px;
}

.side {
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: lightgrey;
}
```

Here is a html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="IplexMC,Survur,Mainkraft,Minecraft Store,iplexmc,iplex,shadowhex iplex review">
    <meta name="author" content="Lubomir Stankov">

    <title> Shte se smenq ot admin panela </title>


    <!-- CSS -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fjalla+One" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/style.css') }}">


</head>

<body>


<div id="particles-js"></div>


<div class="content-box">

    <div class="news-box">
        <h3 class="news-title">News</h3>

        <div class="card mt-1">
            <div class="card-body">
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the
                industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
                scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap
                into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the
                release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
                software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

                Why do we use it?
                It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when
                looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution
                of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many
                desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a
                search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have
                evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).


            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="card mt-1">
            <div class="card-body">
                This is some text within a card body.
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="sidebar">
        <div class="side mt-2">

            Sidebar

            <div class="card mt-2">
                <div class="card-body">
                    This is some text within a card body.
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="side mt-2">

            Sidebar

            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    This is some text within a card body.
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

</div>




<script src="{{ asset('js/particles.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/ptcls.js') }}"></script>
<script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

So when i resize a page the sidebar goes into the news content.. I trying many ways but again without succeed.. I don't know what i do wrongh i hope you may help me! Thanks in advice.

Comment: Yes exactly.. But when i resize page sidebar must goes down!

Comment: Ok, check it again, confirm if thats what you want and I will explain it to you, https://codepen.io/federicomartin/pen/RqGxmE?editors=1100

Comment: Yes i want that..

Comment: @MartinBA can you explain me now.. and one more think i want to help is now how to align it little at the top to be aligned with the news box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I dont't recommend to use floats anymore if you want to make it responsive, I used flexbox to do that, if you want to fully understand what I did read [this](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

You need to set a `display: flex;` for the parent div, and other flex attributes for positioning, and instead of padding-bottom use margin-bottom

```
.content-box {
    border-radius: 25px;
    border: 2px solid;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
    max-width: 70rem;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 20rem;
    background: white;
    margin-bottom: 50rem; /*Changed*/
    display: flex; /*Added*/
    flex-direction: column; /*Added*/
    justify-content: center; /*Added*/
}
```

Then delete the `position: relative` and float for the sidebar, and change the width

```
.sidebar {
    width: 90%; /*Changed*/
    bottom: 520px;
    margin: 30px;
}
```

Also update the news box, delete the float and change the width

```
.news-box {
    background-color: lightgrey;
    width: 90%; /*Changed*/
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 30px;
}
```

That's gonna be ok for mobile, we are using [mobile first](https://getflywheel.com/layout/start-practicing-mobile-first-development/) here, what you need to do for desktop is set a [media query](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px){
  .sidebar {
    width: 24%;
  }

  .news-box {
    width: 70%;
  }

  .content-box {
    flex-direction: row;
  }
}
```

And that should work, read the information and it's gonna be more easy to understand, here you have the [codepen](https://codepen.io/federicomartin/pen/RqGxmE?editors=0100), let me know if that helps you!

Comment: Yeah i understand it! Thanks, but how to align news content and sidebar to be in same level. i mean it have little space at the bottom of that!

Comment: Oh i fixed it.. it was from bootstrap 4 framework (mt-2)

Comment: Yep! that was the problem!